# vertical scroll on css flex container with column direction

Tags: css, scroll, flexbox

I have a div with flex display and column direction and a child div.

Is there a way to make the child div scrollable (vertically) without setting an expicit height?

Thanks

Iliya

```css
.wrapper{  
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
  }

.child{
      height: 100px;
      overflow-y: auto;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tincidunt posuere velit, nec sodales augue viverra et. Cras vehicula in metus ac suscipit. Vivamus porta vestibulum nisl at volutpat. Pellentesque faucibus convallis elit, nec consectetur augue egestas sed. Pellentesque commodo viverra est sit amet dignissim. Nunc imperdiet condimentum tellus, in fermentum est consectetur a. Nunc quis nisi ac massa volutpat elementum et tincidunt quam.

Aenean sed mollis ante. Vivamus et lacus in dolor venenatis semper a ac tellus. Duis sed sollicitudin eros. Integer non volutpat ante, eu molestie lacus. Quisque eros enim, pharetra vitae vehicula a, pretium non metus. Vivamus at eleifend purus. Donec congue porta mattis. Mauris ac lobortis odio. Sed massa purus, blandit vitae massa ac, eleifend porta libero. Quisque magna elit, mollis sed pharetra quis, aliquam vel sem. Nulla tristique aliquet nunc, eget convallis eros feugiat vitae. Etiam posuere dolor at est scelerisque, nec rutrum lorem dignissim. Proin pharetra, massa eu volutpat pretium, dolor velit finibus augue, eget fermentum felis arcu varius dolor. Donec dapibus malesuada nunc et iaculis. Aliquam id ligula fermentum, tincidunt nisl a, molestie ex.

Vestibulum elementum sem id cursus pretium. Sed blandit urna ac ornare pellentesque. Fusce rutrum mauris nec lectus dapibus pulvinar. Donec id fringilla tellus, imperdiet eleifend sem. Morbi ultricies tempus neque ac sodales. Praesent pretium nisi vel justo tempus, eget ultrices orci commodo. Nunc placerat pellentesque condimentum. Duis sollicitudin elit nec neque suscipit, sed accumsan nisl facilisis. Morbi sem magna, aliquam at pretium nec, commodo nec ante. Donec dapibus vehicula felis, ac eleifend leo pharetra id. Vestibulum sagittis justo elit, luctus porta turpis commodo ut.
    </div>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: Sorry to say but I think height is must, if you want scroller @user1510323

Comment: You either need to set the height of `.wrapper` or `.child`, I think.

Comment: the height of the body is set to 100%...